# Is there any way to have a datetime input in Liferay Alloy UI?

Tags: liferay, alloy-ui

According to the docs you can have a date input type: https://portal.liferay.dev/docs/7-1/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/t/building-forms-with-aui-tags

But is there any way to have an input type with date and time? Can't find too much about it.

Comment: Try [`<liferay-ui:input-date />`](http://docs.liferay.com/ce/portal/7.2-ga1/taglibs/util-taglib/liferay-ui/input-date.html).

Comment: there is no way available to select date and time in Liferay Alloy UI. You can use <aui:input/> and select date and time using jquery DateTime picker.